# Site Cannot be reached - Connection times out

Tags: networking, connection

Experiencing a strange issue not related to specific devices, networks or OS's with a WordPress site and wondering if anyone has come across it and if its a server issue?

Basically 3 out of 10 people we tested experience an issue with our site where they get the warning 'Safari cannot connect to page because the network connection was lost.' and 'The site can't be reached. The connection was reset'. The strange thing is its not consistent, for example one persons iphone6 on ios works, anothers doesn't. Same with Chrome on Android. One person is on wifi another not, both experiencing the issue but most others arent. Its hard for me to test as well because none of my 7 testing devices are experiencing the issue!

Attempts at fixes so far include contacting the host to check server status (no sign of issue) upping PHP on the server from 5.5. to 5.6 and checking the available memory (only using 250mb with 400gb available).

Server is shared hosting, Apache 2.2, PHP 5.5, Linux.

I cant see how it can be a local issue if it happening randomly on different devices / OS's so I'm thinking its got to be server related?

Anyone come across this before? Thanks.

If you want to check yourself the site is www.perthminiexcavatorhire.com.au

Comment: I would look at a DNS resolution issue and eliminate that first.

Comment: Site is down for me. I think your ISP is having issues, try a Ping and trace route and see if you can figure out where it drops out.

Comment: @htm11h could you try the site again? It looks like the nameservers were not correct. Ran pingdom and it picked up an error.